# Need help interfacing with Mikroe GSM Click GL865-QUAD with Arduino

Tags: arduino, gsm

I am having trouble figuring out how to interface to mikro electronica's GSM Click form Arduino.  I am trying from Arduino Uno (Rev3) and Arduino Nano. Can you help me please connect and talk to it from Arduino? preferably with the GSM library?

First I changed the Jumper J1 to 5 V (there is some solder across the Jumper is that OK)?

My connections are as follow:
- 5V from Arduino to 5V on GSM CLick
- Ground from Arduino to Gnd on GSM CLick (next to 5V)
- Connect D2 From Arduino to RX
- Connect D3 From Arduino to TX
- Connect D7 from Arduino to RST on GSM Click

I read that I also need power to 3.3 side so 
- Connect the 3.3V from Arduino to 3.3 V
- COnnect GND from Arduino to GND on GSM CLick next to 3.3V pin

When I connect the USB on Arduino the green light turns on, but nothing else.  Here is an excerpt of code I am using...

I checked the power on the 3.3 side of GSM and it is 3.3.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const int RST= 7; // D7 Connected to RST on GSM Click
const int RX=2; // D2 to RX
const int TX=3; // D3 to TX
int STA_value;


SoftwareSerial mySerial(RX,TX); // RX, TX


void setup() {                
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(RST, OUTPUT);   // questo pin serve per accendere il dispositivo GSM

  Serial.begin(9600);  //Initialize Serial connection

  gsmOn(); // turn on GSM


  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }
  Serial.println("Arduino serial initialized!");
  delay(10); 

  mySerial.begin(9600);  
  Serial.println("Software serial initialized!");
  delay(10); 



}




// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
  void loop() 
  {

  sendCommand("AT"); //Set LED ON
  readSerial();


  }


void sendCommand(char* msg)
{ 
  mySerial.print(msg);
  Serial.println(msg);
  delay(1000); 

}

void readSerial()
{
  while(mySerial.available()>0)
  {
    Serial.print(mySerial.read());
    delay(100);  
  }


}



void gsmOn() 
{ 

  digitalWrite(RST, HIGH);   // turn the Phone on
  delay(300); // needs at least 200 ms
  digitalWrite(RST, LOW);  
  delay(300); 
}
```